# check for the greatest number in a list from the last element to the first element

Tags: python, loops

```
a = [3,5,6]
```

how do i check for the greatest number in a list comparing from to last element in the list till the first element

Comment: The line: `a = [3,5,6][1, 3, 2][1, 0, 0, 0]` is not a list, it is a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant for just a `1D` `list`, otherwise you can't exactly compare if a `list` is 'greater than' another `list` (unless you `sum()` them).

So, using a `1D` `list`, such as:

```
l = [1, 2, 5, 6, 9]
```

we can create a `function` to see if it passes your test:

```
def check(lst):
   for i in range(len(lst)-1, 0, -1):
      if not lst[i] > lst[i-1]:
         return False
   return True
```

so we can do some tests, to makes sure that it works:

```
>>> check([1, 2, 5, 8, 9])
True
>>> check([9, 4, 7, 2, 5])
False
>>> check([9, 8, 7, 6, 5])
False
>>> check([9, 8])
False
>>> check([1, 2, 3])
True
```

Comment: This hower is `O(log_N)`, which is far from what the OP describes

Comment: @schwobaseggl Yes, it wasn't that efficient I agree - just what I thought of on the spot, I have updated my answer now with something more efficient (I think)